# Где ошибка в задаче с вхождением элемента в строке?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет

**Задача** Вернуть количество данных гласных в строке

Вот мой код

```
function getCount(str) {
  var vowelsCount = 0;
  var vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];

  var modernStr = str.split('');

    for (var i = 0; i < modernStr.length; ++i) {
        if(modernStr.includes(vowels[i])) vowelsCount++
    }

  return vowelsCount;
}

getCount('aviiiiiii')
```

Но он не работает, не могу понять почему 
Буду благодарен за помощь

Comment: в чем выражается **не работает**?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский некорректно считает количество гласных в строке

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы ошиблись в `if`, правильно так:

```
if(vowels.includes(modernStr[i])) vowelsCount++
```

Comment: Хм, действительно, так работает. Но почему у меня не работало?Можно на пальцах?

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i < modernStr.length; ++i) {
    if(vowels.includes(modernStr[i])) vowelsCount++
}
```

for будет выполнятся modernStr.length раз, значит и перебират нужно будет modernStr[i] а не vowels[i].

Comment: Спасибо большое! Что то сам недопер